# json functions: double quotes added when going through a variable

Tags: mysql, mariadb, json, mariadb-10.2

Im stuck with what it seems simple question, when I create a JSON using the MariaDB/MySQL json functions going through variables, it adds double quotes which is annoying. However, if I don't go through variables, it works fine. Unfortunately I have to go through variables as I'm building my JSON using a recursive function:

1. without variables:

   ```
   declare temp_json JSON;
   set temp_json = json_object('data',json_object("jsonapi",json_object("version", "1.0")));
   select temp_json
   ```

   OUTPUT

   ```
   {"data": {"jsonapi": {"version": "1.0"}}}
   ```
2. with variables

   ```
   declare temp_json JSON;
   declare jsonapiheader JSON;
   set jsonapiheader = json_object("jsonapi",json_object("version", "1.0"));
   set temp_json = json_object('data',jsonapiheader);
   select temp_json
   ```

   OUTPUT

   ```
   {"data": "{\"jsonapi\": {\"version\": \"1.0\"}}"}`
   ```

So how do I do like 2) but with the output of 1) ?

my system:
MariaDB 10.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, generally speaking, there are two types of JSON,

1. JSON-validated text.
2. Binary JSON (Mongo calls it BSON, PostgreSQL calls it JSONB, also Apache Avro).

For reference MariaDB has neither of these. It has a JSON type, but that type is nothing more than un-validated text, [from the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/)

> JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT introduced for compatibility reasons with MySQL's JSON data type. MariaDB implements this as a LONGTEXT rather, as the JSON data type contradicts the SQL standard, and MariaDB's benchmarks indicate that performance is at least equivalent.

If you need a validated column, you need to use a CHECK constraint. So essentially, internally all the functions that "do JSON", essentially read text process it internally and output text.

So the problem you're running into is that `json_object` doesn't know that the value *is* JSON-text. There isn't an easy around that. The only option from a MariaDB's perspective is to implement each function as accepting a value, and another one as accepting a jdoc, or doing it right and [implementing a real type for JSON.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176959/2639)

As a side note, there is one function that does accept two jdocs, one to operate on, and one as an argument. That function is [`JSON_MERGE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_merge/).

See also,

- [Does MariaDB support native JSON column data type?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176959/2639)

I would highly suggest migrating to PostgreSQL if it's not too late. Not just do you get a binary JSON type but you get a rich library of functions, and operators, and indexes for that type.

Comment: I had to google and it appears that MariaDB now supports CHECK constraints. Not sure what they mean when they say that JSON contradicts the SQL standard?

Comment: @Lennart no idea, but I did look it up (also curious there) https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/194681/2639 be interested in their reading too.

Answer (score 2):

@Evan Carroll is certainly right about the general implementation of JSON in MariaDB.
But if you are still going with MariaDB this might help you:

The behavior you describe is a serious bug which is tracked here:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13701
As far as I understood its expected to be fixed with MariaDB-10.2.12.

For the time being I use the following hack:

```
set @jsonapiheader = json_object("jsonapi",json_object("version", CAST(1.0 AS DECIMAL(2,1))));
set @temp_json = concat('{"data":',@jsonapiheader,'}');
select @temp_json, json_valid(@temp_json);
```

Output:

```
{"data":{"jsonapi": {"version": 1.0}}}        |       1
```

Also look at the `CAST` within the first `JSON_OBJECT`. It also works with variables and functions and results in a more accurate JSON output.