# How does the spec store JSON on a table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, json, sql-standard

From this question, [I quoted the docs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192754/json-functions-double-quotes-added-when-going-through-a-variable/192780#192780),

> **"MariaDB implements this as a LONGTEXT rather, as the JSON data type *contradicts* the SQL standard**, and MariaDB's benchmarks indicate that performance is at least equivalent."*

[That spurred a comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192754/json-functions-double-quotes-added-when-going-through-a-variable/192780#comment379117_192780)

> I had to google and it appears that MariaDB now supports CHECK constraints. **Not sure what they mean when they say that JSON contradicts the SQL standard?** – Lennart yesterday

I want to know what they meant too. So what does MariaDB mean when say "contradicts the standard."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SQL:2016

This is from my own read of [ISO/IEC TR 19075-6:2017: SQL support for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c067367_ISO_IEC_TR_19075-6_2017.zip)

Ignoring both (a) the track record of MySQL with regard to the spec, and (b) the fact that they're [now implementing a JSON type](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13701). It seems as if they're referring to this,

> A `<JSON value expression>` may have an optional `<JSON input clause>`. This indicates that the values expression should be parsed as `JSON`. The standardized option is `FORMAT JSON`; implementations may also
> support syntax such as `FORMAT AVRO` or `FORMAT BSON`. When using the `<JSON input clause>`, the `<value expression>` may be either a character string or a binary string.

Essentially, the spec provides for JSON values to come from strings, or binary blobs. The method of making them JSON is done through a decorator which identifies it and its `FORMAT`s. The spec explicitly mentions *"implementation-defined JSON representation option"* it gives BSON and Apache AVRO as examples. It would look something like this (my read of the spec)

```
SELECT str FORMAT JSON BSON;
```

From there the value construction is accessible with the "SQL/JSON data model" and the rest of the spec applies to it. However there is no binary storage mechanism, or stipulation that one *must* be implemented for SQL/JSON. Implementing one doesn't *seem* to contradict the spec. In fact it goes on to say,

> Constructor functions use values of SQL types and produce JSON values
> (JSON objects or JSON arrays) represented in SQL character or **binary string types.**

So they can be represented as a binary type,

> **Query functions evaluate SQL/JSON path language expressions against JSON values, producing values of SQL/JSON types, which are converted to SQL types.**

And SQL queries need to return "SQL types", regardless of if there is a named binary type under the hood. Most databases do that though they return character/varchar/text representations of JSON.

The spec's only example of storing JSON on a table uses strings,

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
emp_id INTEGER,
name CHARACTER VARYING(50),
salary DECIMAL(7,2),
dept_id INTEGER,
json_emp CHARACTER VARYING(5000) )
```

That essentially means the it's serialized to and parsed according to [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159). It's also somewhat amusing that the retrieval of `json_emp` is missing from the spec.

**tldr:** I don't think anything about implementing a binary type *"contradicts"* the spec, as it is explicitly permitted. I think the right word is *"complements."*